# The TXE bit in register SR is not cleared despite writing a value to register DR. STM32F4

Tags: stm32, uart

UART

Why isn't the TXE bit in the SR register cleared?

The Reference Manual says that the TXE bit is cleared if something is written to the DR register.

> It is cleared by a write to the USART_DR register.

I send characters through the terminal(hercules_3-2-8), a number was written to the DR register, but TXE is not cleared.

```
 uint8_t data[5]={"HELLO"};
    while (1)
    {
        HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart3,data,5);
        HAL_Delay(5000);
    }
```

[image]

The delay is 5 seconds, that is, it's not that the bit is switched too quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you expect the TXE to be clear. When sending something out, it sure has been transmitted out long ago if you wait 5 seconds, and surely the TXE bit will be high to signal that transmit register is empty so it can accept data.

It's not you who are writing to DR, it's the function that triggers interrupt based transfers, and a new byte will be written in interrupts when TXE interrupt happens, and when all bytes are transmitted the UART will be ready and TXE will be set.

You will only find the TXE low when UART is busy transferring a byte out and no more bytes can be send to DR until it has been transmitted out.

Comment: Ok.
I was trying to write something like this to detect when the TXE bit is cleared.
        int a=0;
 if((USART3->SR&USART_SR_TXE))
{
 printf("%d\n", a);
        a++;
}
It turns out that if((USART3->SR&USART_SR_TXE)) simply can't be executed while the TXE bit is clear, because data is being transmitted over the UART.

And writing to the DR register, from the Reference Manual, I think I misunderstood.
The Reference Manual was about sending data, not about receiving.
But it wasn't written there.